# Adjusting webcam settings before shooting a photo (v4l2 and fswebcam)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspbian, v4l2

I'm shooting photos with

```
sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1920x1080 --no-banner /media/networkshare/public/"Temp Photo Holder SolidScape Right"/timelapse_$DATE.jpg
```

on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running a recent version of Raspbian.

The script is controlling a Logitech c920 that has adjustable features like focus, brightness, contrast, etc.

I think the reason the 'manual' settings are not being saved is because I call the v4l2-ctl commands, add a delay, and then use fswebcam to shoot, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S")
#sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c focus_auto=false
#sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c focus_absolute=35
sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c brightness=128
sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c contrast=128
sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c saturation=128
sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c gain=15
sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c sharpness=128
sleep 2

sudo v4l2-ctl -c exposure_auto_priority=1

#fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1920x1080 --no-banner /media/networkshare/public/RasPi/"Temp Photo Holder SS"/timelapse_$DATE.jpg

sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1920x1080 --no-banner /media/networkshare/public/"Temp Photo Holder SolidScape Right"/timelapse_$DATE.jpg

sleep 9

sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 1920x1080 --no-banner /media/networkshare/public/"Temp Photo Holder SolidScape Right"/timelapse_$DATE.jpg

sleep 9
```

How can I take a photo with manual settings appended? Maybe I need to add commands to fswebcam inline instead of calling v4l2-ctl first?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working.
No changes were needed.
I wasn't changing settings dramatically enough to notice a difference in the output.